# Dataverse plugin not sending logs to Application Insights

Tags: plugins, azure-application-insights, microsoft-dynamics, dataverse

I have a Dataverse Plugin which is registered on a Dynamics 365 environment. I want to send logs from the plugin to Azure Application Insights. I configured the export of data to Application Insights. Dataverse logs do appear in Application Insights but the plugin logs not.

I created a Dynamics Plugin and added ILogger to log information to Application Insights like this:

```
ILogger logger = (ILogger)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ILogger));
logger.LogInformation("Some log information");
```

and as described in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/application-insights-ilogger

I also configured the export of dataverse data to application insights based on following instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/set-up-export-application-insights

Yet, no traces appear in Application Insights (i also check other tables in application insights)

Neither other methods on `ILogger` write traces to Application Insights.

The method `ILogger.IsEnabled(LogLevel)` returns `False` for every LogLevel.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable logging for plugins? In order to do that go to the legacy application clicking "Advanced Settings":
[image]

In "Advanced Settings" go to Settings -> Administration:
[image]

In Administration click "System Settings".
In the "System Settings" popup go to the "Customization" tab and choose "All" in "Logging Level" because the value by default is "Exception".
[image]

Comment: The setting was already set to "All" in my case. I also tried to switch it off and on. But still it is not working.